# Can not remove a container image from the Google Container Registry from Console

Tags: google-container-registry, google-cloud-console

I have project OWNER right, but can not remove image from console, 
Delete is disabled and there is tag "you do not have pemission to delete this image". 
By gcloud everithing works.
I remove buckets - _cloudbuild and artifacts.appspot.com but it was restored after first image build.
How can i resolve this situation?

Comment: Am seeing the same issue and additionally I cannot add or remove tags to stored images. This is a fairly recent regression as I performed these operations a few weeks ago

Comment: @Madden same, I also performed these operations a few days ago and in other projects everithig works very well.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works correctly using `gcloud` means that the GCP API is not the issue. Maybe is a glitch in the console.

First ensure that your Cloud Console session corresponds to the user with owner permissions (could be that you've sign up in `gcloud` with a different account).

If that is correct, I'd file a [support request](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=bg#support-plans) or create an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=1162610) case.

This seems like a case that needs to be addressed by the GCP team and StackOverflow is not the best channel to get support for that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In both cases I am doing this with same account (email signed in). I try sign out, signe in, delete all cookies from browse but noting helps.
Thank you i make:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144836081

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's notice:

> Project owners and editors are currently unable to edit tags or delete
>   images in the Container Registry UI. The workarounds are to either use
>   the command line or grant the Storage Object Viewer IAM role. A fix is
>   expected by December 5th.

I'll put the [link to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing), so that other people know what to do until the issue is fixed:

I use this command to delete images while the Console does not work:

`gcloud container images delete [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG] --force-delete-tags`